# Error while deploying spring security application on ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, spring-security

I am struggling with below error while deploying the application on ec2 instance

10:59:13,129 [localhost-startStop-1] [] [ERROR] [ContextLoader].[initWebApplicationContext()]:312 :: Context initialization failed
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/springframework/security/web/FilterChainProxy, method:  signature: (Lorg/springframework/security/web/SecurityFilterChain;)V) Expecting to find object/array on stack

When I remove http tags from security context file, we are able to deploy the application on ec2 isntance.

How ever same war is getting deployed on our local instance(windows).

Please find below our security context file

```
<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled" authentication-manager-ref="mizuAuthenticationManager" ></global-method-security>

<beans:bean id="mizuPropertiesHolder" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="locations">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>classpath*:mizu-conf.properties</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
</beans:bean>                   

<beans:bean id="preAuthFilter" class="com.converse.mizu.service.filter.UrlParametersAuthenticationFilter">

</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="mizuAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="com.converse.mizu.service.security.MizuAuthenticationEntryPoint">
     <beans:constructor-arg name="loginUrl" value="/" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="rememberMeFilter" class= "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="authenticationManager" ref="mizuAuthenticationManager" />
        <beans:constructor-arg name="rememberMeServices" ref="mizuRememberMeServices"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="mizuUserDetailsService" class="com.converse.mizu.service.security.UserDetailsServiceImpl"></beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="mizuAuthenticationProvider" class="com.converse.mizu.service.security.MizuAuthenticationProvider"></beans:bean>


<beans:bean id="mizuRememberMeServices" class= "com.converse.mizu.service.security.CustomTokenBasedRememberMeService">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="key" value="${remembeMeCoockie.key}"></beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:constructor-arg name="userDetailsService" ref="mizuUserDetailsService"></beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:property name="tokenValiditySeconds" value="2592000" />
        <beans:property name="cookieName" value="${remembeMeCoockie.name}" />
        <beans:property name="cookiePath" value="/" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider" class= "org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="key" value="${remembeMeCoockie.key}"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="logoutSuccessHandler" class="com.converse.mizu.service.security.LogoutSuccessHandler" >
    <beans:property name="logoutSuccessUrl" value="/"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
    <beans:property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
    <beans:property name="expiredUrl" value="/" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sas" class= "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
    <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />

<http pattern="/js/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/css/**" security="none" />  
<http pattern="/img/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/font/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/index.html*" security="none" />
<http pattern="/rest/url/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/rest/user/resetpwd/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/rest/uiads/analytics/uispec/**" security="none" />

<http entry-point-ref="http403EntryPoint" pattern="/autologin">
    <custom-filter ref="preAuthFilter" position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
    <session-management invalid-session-url="/" >
        <concurrency-control session-registry-ref="sessionRegistry"  max-sessions="1" />
    </session-management>
</http>

<http use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="mizuAuthenticationEntryPoint" >

    <intercept-url pattern="/rest/signup/selfserve/register/account**"  access="hasRole('CREATE_ACCOUNT')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/html/account/register.html"  access="hasRole('CREATE_ACCOUNT')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/html/adStudio.htm**"  access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/html/adcreator.htm**"  access="isAuthenticated() and hasRole('AD_CREATOR_TOOL')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/rest/signup/**"  access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/rest/**"  access="isAuthenticated()"/>

    <custom-filter ref="mizuAuthenticationProcessingFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
    <custom-filter ref="rememberMeFilter" position="REMEMBER_ME_FILTER"/>
    <custom-filter ref="concurrencyFilter" position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER"/>
    <session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas"/>

    <logout invalidate-session="true" success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler"/>
    <access-denied-handler ref="accessDeniedHandler"/>

</http>

<beans:bean id="mizuAuthenticationProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
  <beans:property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sas" />
  <beans:property name="authenticationManager"  ref="mizuAuthenticationManager"/>
  <beans:property name="usernameParameter" value="username" />
  <beans:property name="passwordParameter" value="password" />
  <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="loginFailureHandler"/>
  <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="loginSuccessHandler"/>   
  <beans:property name="rememberMeServices" ref="mizuRememberMeServices" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Register authentication manager for form login-->
<authentication-manager alias="mizuAuthenticationManager">
       <authentication-provider ref="mizuAuthenticationProvider"/>
       <authentication-provider ref="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider"/>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="http403EntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint"></beans:bean>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean when you say "When I remove http tags from security context file, we are able to deploy the application"? This alone would certainly fail since the bean springSecurityFilterChain would no longer be defined. Do you by chance remove <global-method-security> as well?

Comment: @RobWinch Prior to removing http tags the deployment on tomcat didn't proceed at all. Then I have removed all <http> namespace tags in security context file and left <global-method-security> the way it was. Then I was able to deploy the application on tomcat. I have not got any error at the time of deployment with respect to spring security files. This i have done to check the root cause of the problem. Here what deployment mean, tomcat accepting the WAR file.

Comment: Now the application is running on ec2 instance. Here is what i have done as a last resort: Our ec2 instance has two jdk version 6 and 7, uninstalled both and installed latest one(7), removed tomcat and installed again. this solved the issue, but i am wondering why it is giving error if we have two jdk verions

Comment: Can you post your web.xml for when it fails and when you have removed the <http> namespace tags?